# Allowed memory size exhausted with Manually Generate Pagination in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am in processes to generate an array of numbers from available starting and ending numbers but I am facing **Allowed memory size exhausted** error while generating 1 million records. I do not want to store any information in the memory. So, Please review and guide that what is the issue or how I can iterate the code below to achieve this.

```
    $start = "0";
    //$end    = "5000";
    $end    = "16777216";
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
        $range[] = "Number $i";
    }
    //$total=count($range);
    $perPage = 25;
    $currentPage = request()->input("page") ?? 1;
    $startingPoint = ($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage;
    $paginatedItems = array_slice($range, $startingPoint, $perPage, true);
    $paginated = new Paginator(
        $paginatedItems,
        count($range),
        $perPage,
        $currentPage,
        ['path' => request()->url(), 'query' => request()->query()]
    );
    return $paginated;
```

This code works well and generate the required results and then put these results in **Laravel 9** Manual Pagination but when I try to generate a million or more records, it through the PHP default expection which I want to avoid based on the offset. Thank You

Comment: I mean the error is obvious, the $range array stores the value in memory until the return is reached. So you will have to either increase resources for your server/app or create a smaller Paginator. All in all, I don't see why you would need to store all the numbers in an array. You could simply calculate the start and end values by using the page and perPage values

Comment: If you don't want to store any additional information in memory then don't pre-generate the entire `$range` array and then do an array_slice, just generate the sliced part only from the start. I know you might just be using a placeholder for your actual code here but the solution is the same. Get only a single page of data to instantiate the paginator instance with. Don't get all the data and then slice it